# Simple GET WebRequest VB 2010

Tags: php, vb.net, webrequest

I got a simple Question:
For testing purpose I setup a little php file, accepting two GET paramenters 'category' and 'content'. By navigating to the URL: 
http://server.com/saveload.php?category=Test&content=HelloWorld
the php file creates a text file named Test.txt and writes HelloWorld into it.

Now I created a simple VB application. Because I wanted to replicate my recent goals, I simply wrote into my Form_Load method:

```
Dim url As String = "http://server.com/saveload.php?category=Test&content=HelloWorld"
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
webClient.DownloadString(url)
```

How it looks to me, it should do the exact same thing as a normal request via my browser. But instead it returns an HTTP status response 403 - Forbidden.
But why? In order to access the webspace you do not need any credentials, everyone I asked had no problems to access the URL and get a success feedback.
I also tried a POST request, same result.
I use the DownloadString method, because the GetResult Method, that I used before did the same 403.

What is my fault?

Comment: What are the headers send to your php script? That looks like a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue

Comment: I do not send any headers. It is a simple use of VB standard methods.

Comment: There is your problem, without any headers Apache will assume that the request comes from a different domain and rejects it. Have a look at the response headers.

Comment: Ok, you were right: The support of the webspace told me to send a user agent within the header. Now it works :D

Comment: cool, mark the question as resolved. Cheers

Comment: If you tell me how...